# Ejecutar automáticamente el click con un evento addEventListener cuando termine de cargar la página

Tags: javascript

Agradezco puedan darme una idea de como podría ejecutar el click de un botón automáticamente, el cual activa una función con un evento addEventListener para que el contenido de dicha función esté disponible cuando termine de cargar la página.

Gracias

```
document.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
  //contenido
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Todos los controladores de eventos adjuntos con `.on ()` o uno de sus métodos de acceso directo se activan cuando se produce el evento correspondiente. Sin embargo, se pueden disparar manualmente con el método `.trigger ()`. Una llamada a `.trigger ()` ejecuta los controladores en el mismo orden en que lo estarían si el usuario desencadenara el evento de forma natural:

```js
function myFunction() {
  alert("Hello! I am an alert box!");
}
function trigger(){
  $("#btn").trigger("click");
}

trigger()
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<p>Haga clic en el botón para mostrar un cuadro de alerta.</p>
<button onclick="myFunction()" id="btn">Modal desde alert</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Esto lo que va hacer es ejecutar un alert inicial sin necesidad de presionar el botón, si no presionas volverá aparecer el alert.

Espero sea lo que estás buscando.

Comment: dnlb Gracias por responder, con el botón me funciona bien para lograr hacer full screen de mi pagina. Ahora lo que busco es poder lograr que al cargar mi pagina automaticamente se dispare dicha función para que sin necesidad presionar el botón  quedé full screen. Siento que no me ha funcionado es por que uso addEventListener . Lo intenté de esta forma: window.onload = function(){
  document.getElementById('btnScreen').click();})

Answer (score 1):

Propongo esta forma de hacerlo:

Tienes un botón el cual le asignas un `id`

```
<button id="activador">Hola</button>
```

Posterior en tu script lo compones del siguiente modo:

```
let boton = document.getElementById("activador")
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  boton.addEventListener("click", hola)
  function hola() {
    console.log(1)
  }
  hola()
})
```

Donde:

- al objeto `window` le asigno un *listener* en el evento `DOMContentLoaded`
- a la variable donde recuperé el botón le asigno un *listener* en su evento `click` y le paso como segundo parámetro el nombre de la función que se ejecutará
- Posterior creo la función
- Finalmente invoco a la función; *esta línea ayudará a que el console.log se ejecute*

Comment: Hola, gracias por responder. Intenté con tu ejemplo; sin embargo no logro hacer que se ejecute automaticamente cuando termina de cargar el navegador , actualmente me funciona solo cuando doy click en el botón. Mi código lo tengo de la siguiente forma:              window.onload=function(){
    
document.getElementById("btnScreen").addEventListener("click", function (event) {

    if (document.fullscreenElement) {
        document.exitFullscreen();
    } else {
        document.documentElement.requestFullscreen();
    }

}, false);

Answer (score 0):

Guarda el elemento en una variable

```
// Este es un ejemplo, puedes utilizar cualquier selector (byId, byClass, etc.)
const el = document.querySelector('.mi-elemento');
```

Añade el evento disparador al elemento

```
el.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  // Código
})
```

Toma el evento de carga del navegador

```
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
   // Ejecuta manualmente el evento de click de tu elemento
   el.click()
})
```